# Area Under Half Normal Distribution is too big

Tags: transformation, normal-distribution

I have a project where I need to look what I think is a half normal distribution.
x is roughly normally distributed and centered at 0.  What I need to look at is y = |x|.
I've never used half normal distributions before.
To get more familiar with it I've been experimenting with both R and excel.
I created a standard normal distribution and verify that the area under the curve is one.
Then, I doubled all those probabilities for z scores greater than or equal to 0.
I verified this method by thinking about it, and using the R package "extraDist."
Now the rub is that the  area under the half normal is equal to 1.4.

Here is a simple table to illustrate my problem;

```
Z   norm    half

-6.00   0.00    0.00

-5.00   0.00    0.00

-4.00   0.00    0.00

-3.00   0.00    0.00

-2.00   0.05    0.00

-1.00   0.24    0.00

0.00    0.40    0.80

1.00    0.24    0.48

2.00    0.05    0.11

3.00    0.00    0.01

4.00    0.00    0.00

5.00    0.00    0.00

6.00    0.00    0.00
```

I am pretty certain that the area under any pdf should not exceed 1.
Can someone please enlighten me?

Best of luck, thanks!